# When to use :something => 'something' and when to use :something, 'something'?

Tags: watir-webdriver

Basic Watir WebDriver commands are given here:

```
http://watirwebdriver.com/web-elements/
```

In most cases, the author uses `:something => 'something'`

In a single case, the author uses `:something, 'something'`

Is there any difference in the implementation of these specifications?

Are there cases where one would fail and the other would work?

It seems to me that there's no difference. Or more precisely, it seems to me that in the limited subset of examples that I tested, there's no difference.

Another question. Due to my advanced years, I've grown accustomed to having things inside parentheses. Once again, I've tested both, and found no difference. Are there cases where the use of parentheses in the above examples would fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Locator Format**

While the Watir code has to do different things based on the format provided - ie a single hash vs two parameters - from perspective of a Watir user (ie you), they are the same. You can use whichever you prefer.

A long time ago, Watir only supported locating elements with a single property. At that point, the only supported format was the `:something, 'something'`.

When Watir moved to support locating elements with multiple properties, the option to use the hash, `:something => 'something'` became available. The original format, `:something, 'something'`, to my knowledge, was kept for backward compatibility.

So if you are just locating an element based on a single property, you can use either format. If you are using multiple properties, you have to use a hash - `:something => 'something', :something2 => 'something2'`.

I suggest just using the hash format as it keeps things consistent and is easier to change when adding additional properties in the future.

**Parenthesis**

For your question about the parenthesis, that is a Ruby thing rather than a Watir thing. The parenthesis are only required if the parsing of the statement by Ruby would be ambiguous.

For Watir locators, you pretty much always needs the parenthesis. For example:

```
# Parenthesis are required
browser.link(:id => '1').text

# Without, an exception occurs - undefined method `text' for "1":String (NoMethodError)
browser.link :id => '1'.text
```

I guess one point where you could go without parenthesis is if you had a line that just initialized an element. The above could be re-written without parenthesis by breaking it to two lines.

```
e = browser.link :id => '1'
e.text
```

Again, I would suggest that always using parenthesis makes the thought process easier.

Comment: +1 just for 'I suggest just using the hash format as it keeps things consistent and is easier to change when adding additional properties in the future.'

Answer (score 2):

You should always use `:something => 'something'`.

`:something, 'something'` is the old API. It still works but it could be removed soon.

I have updated the documentation that you refer to, now it uses the new API everywhere.